# How to disable or avoid pylint warnings for monkey-patched object: "Instance of 'xxx' has no 'yyy' member"

Tags: python, pylint

I have a class in my system that represents an RPC interface to a remote system.  It provides a method for each RPC method.  The methods are generated from an api spec at runtime.  So I have code that looks kind of like:

```
class api:
    pass

for name, method in api_spec:
    setattr(api, name, method)
```

Then I have calls like:

```
x = api()
x.some_remote_call()
```

Pylint (v0.26.0) reports this at the call site:

```
[E1101, ...] Instance of 'api' has no 'some_remote_call' member
```

Question:
Is there a way I can disable or avoid this warning?

I would like to avoid annotating every call; it's just not practical in this codebase.  My fallback is just to give up on warning E1101 altogether, but apart from this case it's a very useful warning.

Ideally, I'd like to modify or annotate the api class somehow to tell pylint not to generate the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible answer.  Adding a getattr method shuts pylint up:

```
class api:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        raise AttributeError(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `--ignored-classes` option which allow to specify some classes whose members shouldn't be checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to suppress warnings with a regex.

```
import warnings    
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '.*Instance.*',)
```

Where the keywords within .*Your keywords here.* will trigger the ignore rule.

You may need to play with the regex match string to get the desired effect.  You will want to enter the regex match that is most specific to your actual warning.  'Instance' may not be  good choice, since you might want to catch other true warnings of "Instance of".  You can also reset this filter once you pass your code block as well.

```
warnings.resetwarnings()
```